# Buffering versus streaming a large dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I need to apply 10,000 to 20,000 unique filters to a dataset of 50M rows with 8 columns and proper indexing.

My current approach is to dynamically generate and execute these queries one at a time:

```
var stats = (from a in db.AggregatedStats
             where a.StatType.StartsWith("TOTAL_ITEM")
             select a);

// Add more filters to the WHERE clause

foreach (var stat in stats) { // Process the data }
```

I believe this method is called "streaming" data from SQL Server to MoveNext().

Would it be more efficient to buffer the data into the program's memory?

```
var stats = (from a in db.AggregatedStats
             where a.StatType.StartsWith("TOTAL_ITEM")
             select a).ToList();
```

Then apply filters to this list of entities instead:

```
var result = (from a in stats
              where a.Region.Equals(region)
              select a);
```

This would effectively reduce the number of SQL Server queries from 10,000 to 1.

In this case, would buffering the dataset into the program be worth the extra RAM compared to the time it takes to stream the data from 10,000 queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Negative. Deferring the enumeration from the database until the last possible second eliminates you getting data that is just going to be invalidated pushed into memory (which will just balloon the memory used for this application). That is the approach that your current sample uses (since it doesnt actually get invoked until the `foreach` starts) and should be the most performant.

I think you might be confused; when you write

```
var stats = (from a in db.AggregatedStats
         where a.StatType.StartsWith("TOTAL_ITEM")
         select a);
```

Nothing has actually happened - `stats` simply contains an iterator that knows how to get the data, and until you call `ToList()` or enumerate that query with a `foreach`, nothing is actually requested, which is why you get performance.

Comment: I understand that LINQ builds the query, then executes it only when data is requested. So even if all of the filters (ie. where clauses) will be applied to this broad dataset, I should stick with streaming each query? There IS overlap. Some data from one filter spills into others. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused - requesting the minimum amount of data by letting the provider construct the SQL query should be the best situation, no? Regardless of your filter overlap, as long as you can construct the query appropriately, nothing is wrong.

Comment: True, so in this case, would you recommend investing in more RAM? SQL Server is sitting on 16GB of RAM, an SSD, and a 3.3 GHz Xenon. Please let me know if you have any recommendations to improve performance outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I'm assuming that your original problem is that this query is slow? Has the table structure been appropriately indexed? What SQL optimizations have been made?

Comment: There is a non-unique, non-clustered index on StatType and Date. It includes 5 other columns. Now that I think about it, I should add indexes to other combinations of the columns. I ran SQL Server Profiler months ago when I was using `.ToList()`, so I should also go through that again. Also, should I be including all of the other columns on these indexes? The size of the index is a tad larger than the database itself.

Answer (score 2):

I’d take some time to analyze those filters and see which ones are filtering out most of the data. You’ll probably find that there are 10-20 filters that filter out 95% of the data.

If you can identify top X filters that filter out most of the data then you can just apply query with those filters to database. What you get as a result will be a limited set of records that you can buffer and additionally filter in memory.